# How to define a more customElements for same Class

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I jsut tried to define new Custom Elements.

```js
// the class
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    // mandatory super call to upgrade the current context
    super();
    // any other Class/DOM related procedure
    this.setAttribute('custom-attribute', 'value');
this.innerText = 'new element';
  }
}

// its mandatory definition
customElements.define('my-el', MyEl);

// the JS way to create a custom element
const newMe = new MyEl();


document.body.appendChild(newMe);
```

Defining a new element of the same class will cause an error:
**"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry':
 this constructor has already been used with this registry"**

But i want to define new elements for same class.
Could you suggest a way to display multiple items from the same class (MyEl).
Thank in advance!

Comment: I think you're going to have trouble setting an attribute in the constructor. Attributes cannot be imposed by the element, they can only come from the HTML during construction, or via .setAttribute() after construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`customElements.define('my-el', MyEl)` must be called only once to tell the browser you have a new `<my-el>` tag (aka to *define* a custom element).

Then you can *create* multiple elements just by using `new`:

```
const newMe1 = new MyEl();
const newMe2 = new MyEl();
```

Or `createElement()`:

```
const newMe1 = document.createElement( 'my-el' )
const newMe2 = document.createElement( 'my-el' )
```

Or, in the html code:

```
<my-el></my-el>
<my-el></my-el>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just try with an anonymous constructor and extend your MyEl:

```js
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
  // your definitions
}

customElements.define("my-better-element", class extends MyEl { })
customElements.define("my-second-element", class extends MyEl { })
```

Comment: How is that any useful?

Comment: @connexo, Only if you want a better name for the original, but you are otherwise happy with it. That's what happened to me today.

Comment: @connexo In my case, our org has a component library that's been around and used by different teams at different versions. So, our site-wide header uses an old version and isn't ready to upgrade, but our page *needs* to use the newer version. We don't want to iframe it, so we need to load both.